# What does "R"c mean when mapping a network drive using this function

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, network-drive

I copied code to map a network drive from http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=616519 to map the drive and http://cjwdev.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/delete-network-drive/ to delete the drive. I want to know what "R"c means in this code:

```
    RemoveNetworkDrive("R"c, True)
```

which came from the first link and then I want to know how to simulate this notation in a variable so I can check for the first available drive and map the network drive to that letter. I would Google search it but since I don't know what "R"c means it makes it difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"R"c` is the `Char` version of `"R"`. You use it when you want to specify a character rather than a string.

MSDN has some details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903372%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> You can also create an array of strings from a single string by using the `String.Split` Method. The following example demonstrates the reverse of the previous example: it takes a shopping list and turns it into an array of shopping items. The separator in this case is an instance of the `Char` data type; thus it is appended with the literal type character `c`.

```
Dim shoppingList As String = "Milk,Eggs,Bread"
Dim shoppingItem(2) As String
shoppingItem = shoppingList.Split(","c)
```

Comment: thank you. I always wondered how you do char literals in VB.NET

Answer (score 1):

It converts your string "R" to a char, as requested from function

```
Public Shared Sub RemoveNetworkDrive(ByVal DriveLetter As Char, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the syntax for a [character literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sx7t66b.aspx), basically - it's the equivalent of `'R'` in C#, if that makes it any clearer.